# Issue to compile lftp

Tags: c, linux, gcc

A friend of mine has a problem to build lftp-4.4.15.
argmatch.c includes  and the compiler complains about an enum

```
typedef enum { _Bool_must_promote_to_int = -1, false = 0, true = 1 } _Bool;
```

The Error is:

```
./stdbool.h:115:70: Error: expected »;«, identifier or »(« before »_Bool«
```

If he experimentally defines this type himself and name it Bool instead of _Bool, the compiler doesn't complain. But system-headers are allowed to define identifiers with an underscore, so I don't understand what's the issue here.

Comment: Why so archaic version? This appears to be a know issue: https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/59

Comment: `_Bool` came with C99.